# Chrome OSX SSL This certificate has an invalid issuer

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ssl, keychain

I am getting an 'invalid issuer' error when trying to access a local site. As can be seen in the screenshot, the root CA certificate has been imported and trusted. So, why do I still get this error?

The certificate works correctly in Firefox after importing the CA cert.

[image: Root cert]

[image: Server cert]

Comment: We have exactly the same problem: Generated our own root certificate and installed fine as trusted on Windows (Chrome/Firefox) and Mac (Firefox only). In Mac/Chrome we get the same error "This certificate has an invalid issuer" even though the root certificate is marked as trusted in the System key chain.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS does not support `Name Constraints`. Removing this property from the root certificate solved this issue in our case. For background see: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95600/are-x-509-nameconstraints-on-certificates-supported-on-os-x

(You don't appear to be using this property according to the screenshots, but I'm still posting this as it might be a valid solution for others)

Comment: Note: marking the `Name Constraints` as not "critical" also solved this problem. (But you should determine yourself if this is smart: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/30978/39516)